# JaxWsDynamicClientFactory.newInstance().createClient() and wsdl2Java inconsistencies

Tags: web-services, cxf, wsdl2java

So I'm trying to use JaxWsDynamicClientFactory to dynamically create the SEI classes. Running the below code

```
JaxWsDynamicClientFactory def = JaxWsDynamicClientFactory.newInstance();
def.createClient("http://localhost:8080/TheTestService/TestService?wsdl");
```

generates classes:

com.mycompany.project.service.GetProducts

com.mycompany.project.service.GetStatus

running:

```
wsdl2Java -d "C/:outputdir" "http://localhost:8080/TheTestService/TestService?wsdl"
```

generates classes

com.mycompany.project.service.ServiceInterface

com.mycompany.project.service.GetProducts

com.mycompany.project.service.GetStatus

com.mycompany.project.service.impl.ServiceInterface

Furthermore, when I try to call

```
client.invoke("getProducts", 0);
```

I get:

```
org.apache.cxf.common.i18n.UncheckedException: No operation was found with the name {http://impl.service.project.mycompany.com/}getProducts.
```

which I guess makes sense as  there would be nothing named getProducts generated at impl.service.project.mycompany.com. However since I wrote the web service, I know for a fact the web service interface has the method getProducts(int id).

What am I doing wrong here? According to the CXF documentation, the dynamic client factory uses the same code generator as the wsdl2Java tool. If that's the case, why aren't the same classes generated?

Thanks,

Chuck

Answer (score 2):

First, `JaxWsProxyFactoryBean` to create a Client is ok. I solved the problem, you must keep your service interface and `implementor` in the same class package. When `JaxWsDynamicClientFactory` is used to dynamically create the SEI classes, it would find `implementor` in the same package path, it is a default setting. But according to the API, you can set your `targetNamespace`.

I have no idea of the differences between `JaxWsProxyFactoryBean` and `JaxWsDynamicClientFactory`.

Answer (score 0):

I think theare is some bug, cause i had .wsdl and one one of the classes generated with wsdl2java had property `getItem` BUT  `JaxWsDynamicClientFactory.newInstance().createClient()` has generated this class with property getItems. So my advance is to examine the  methods of class you want use(i mean,methods of classes generated with `JaxWsDynamicClientFactory.newInstance().createClient()` ).To achive this use ref